# Instantiating windows form at runtime from database name C#

Tags: c#

I am having trouble instantiating a form in c# whose name i retrieve from a database, i have eliminated namespaces completely just to be sure i am not getting the object name wrong but still every time the code runs, the object returns as null instead of being the appropriate form.

```
private static Object CreateObjectInstance(string strObjectName)
{
    Object obj = null; // Temporary object

    try
    {
        if (strObjectName.LastIndexOf(".") == -1) // If there is no '.' in the object name
            strObjectName = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name + "." + strObjectName;

        obj = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().CreateInstance(strObjectName);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        clsAdmFunctions.RecordException(ex); // Record error to the database
        MessageBox.Show("Error instantiating the object\n\nDescription : "+ex.Message, "Object Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        obj = null;
    }

    return obj;
}

public static Form CreateForm(string strFormName)
{
    return (Form)CreateObjectInstance(strFormName);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried calling `Activator.CreateInstance` using a hard coded fully qualified class name? If that works then you can work backwards and make sure you are passing in the correct string.

Comment: Lots of iffy assumptions here, particularly that the assembly name matches the namespace name and that the form type is stored in the EXE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your idea that assembly name is a part of your class name. True you need access to your assembly, but ultimately a class name is just `Namespace.Class` name. If you provide your actual namespace along with the class, then it works. Change your method to this, perhaps:

```
private static T CreateInstance<T>(string fullyQualifiedClassName)
{
    try
    {
        return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(fullyQualifiedClassName));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        clsAdmFunctions.RecordException(ex); // Record error to the database
        MessageBox.Show("Error instantiating the object\n\nDescription : " + ex.Message, "Object Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

In other words you need the namespace too if you're saving it in the database. Just save `class.GetType()` as such or `class.GetType().ToString()` after which you will see the namespace too saved. The reason is you can have classes with same name, `namespace1.Person` and `namespace2.Person` in the same assembly.

If you need to read all the namespaces in an assembly, you can do:

```
 foreach(var type in Assembly.WhateverAssembly().GetTypes())
     //print type.Namespace;
```

You're stuck if you dont know the exact namespace. May be you can **assume** it to be

```
var namespace = Assembly.WhateverAssembly().GetTypes()[0].Namespace;
```

---

You need to have namespaces for your classes, doing otherwise is against .NET's design. If you really really want to have no namespaces for your Forms, you just need to specify just the class name, exclude the assembly name. Just call:

```
CreateInstance<MyForm>("MyForm");
```

provided `MyForm` is `global` and the assembly is just the same. If forms are in different assembly, then load it first using `Assembly.Load` or `Assembly.LoadFrom` and then create instance.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but i have deleted the explicit namespace declaration in every class, thus they should all be in the exact namespace, correct?

Comment: @ReidGarwin I updated my answer. If there are no namespaces at all then they all belong to "global::" scope. If so you need not specify namespace, just passing the class name as such will do.

Comment: Thank you, if (strObjectName.LastIndexOf(".") == -1) // If there is no '.' in the object name
            strObjectName = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name + "." + strObjectName; was what needed to go away... works great now.

Answer (score 1):

Your key method `CreateObjectInstance` should work OK so I am guessing it is the parameter being passed in? In my example I've shown how to include full namespace and class name etc:

```
namespace Example.SubFolder
{
    internal class frmAdmAbout
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace Example.ActualApp
{
    using System;
    using System.Reflection;

    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var newItem = CreateObjectInstance("Example.SubFolder.frmAdmAbout");
            if (newItem == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to create!");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Successfully created!");
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static Object CreateObjectInstance(string strObjectName)
        {
            Object obj = null;

            try
            {
                if (strObjectName.LastIndexOf(".") == -1)
                    strObjectName = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name + "." + strObjectName;

                obj = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().CreateInstance(strObjectName);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error instantiating the object\n\nDescription : " + ex.Message);
                obj = null;
            }

            return obj;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My parameter is the exact name of the windows form. PS i cant spot any relevant changes on your code snippet?

Comment: I haven't made any changes to your method because it should work assuming your class is named correctly and this example was showing that. What ARE you passing? Can you give an example? I.e. Your form is called Form1 so you are passing CreateObjectInstance("Form1")?

Comment: indeed... passing "frmAdmAbout" where the form name is frmAdmAbout.cs, Its in a folder called "Forms" in the project, but i have made sure that every class is in the project namespace...

Comment: I still think it is the parameter being passed in that is wrong. Is the form in the same assembly as this method? If it is then double-check your namespaces, I have updated my example to show how to include namespace etc.

Comment: Can it be a different assembly than the form if its in the same project though? How do I go about checking if its in the same assembly?

Comment: @ReidGarwin no, if they are the same project, then its the same assembly.